# Folding of bulliform cells

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

How do bulliform cells cause a leaf to fold in half when the leaf looses water? Also, how would these bulliform cells be arranged to cause the cell to instead curl up?

Comment: This is a really well written paper which answers at least your first question. As long as the curling up is concerned, they curl up when there is insufficient water and they curl in order to avoid excessive transpiration. There is something about this in the *Discussion* part, check it out. http://www.bio.uaic.ro/publicatii/anale_vegetala/issue/2010F2/01-2010F2.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curling up is due to turgor pressure. Quoting from wikipedia

> Loss of turgor pressure in these cells causes leaves to "roll up" during water stress

More scientific reference , [on morphology](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&ved=0CFQQFjAKahUKEwjJ3M2P_onIAhWFopQKHSt1BqQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftao.wordpedia.com%2Fpdf_down.aspx%3Ffilename%3DJO00001031_36-1_85-97&usg=AFQjCNHeiE6fEGnRDKwiKT7j_yYHQrdyCQ&sig2=I3OnSTX4K0xc6IpfcwO0yg&bvm=bv.103073922,d.dGo&cad=rja),  [on mechanism](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1516-89132008000100014), [on development](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25213398), [some genetics](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20494951) and [on physics](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24306471).

Comment: Can I get a deeper explanation of the mechanism in layman's language?

Comment: In layman's term, According to [this](http://www.scielo.br/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S1516-89132008000100014) paper, these cells loose their water and reduces their volume in water scarcity. This osmotic flow of water creates pressure which pushes plasma membrane of cell to cell wall (which _I think_ is causing '**curl up**' phenotype') However same paper has also mentioned other hypothesis for this mechanism like use of 'pectin' as water reservoir.